# Сочетание «с большой буквы»

Tags: орфография

Почему это словосочетание пишется так? Тут же вроде как должен быть творительный падеж, но на деле что-то другое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если предлагается все буквы написать большими, то да, творительный падеж: "большими буквами". А в этом выражении подразумевается только та буква, с которой *начинается* слово: написать (начав с чего, с какой буквы?) с большой буквы (родит. падеж).

Comment: Как говорят музыканты : (начинаем, играем) с третьей цифры, пожалуйста...